# Javascript and HTML validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code, I am trying to show the "required" span text when the user didn't meet the requirements on each field. But it's not working. What's wrong with this?

```js
function validate() {
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var fname = document.registration.fname;
  if (fname.value === "") {
    spans[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    spans[0].setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name='registration' align='center'>
  <fieldset name='registration' class='fieldset-auto-width'>
    <div>
      <label for='fname'><b>FirstName:</b>
      </label>
      <input type='text' name='fname' placeholder='Enter First Name' value='' required='required' />
      <span id='errfn' class='error'> required</span>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='validate();' />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: On my CSS code, the class 'error' visibility is hidden and will only show up when an invalid input was entered and that is through my javascript code above.

Comment: Can you eleborate  on 'it's not working'?

Comment: @user4932301 — Can you provide a minimal test case that actually demonstrates the problem? At the moment, the require message is always visible.

Comment: Your code translates to `if there's no fname, set it to visible, otherwise also`...

Comment: On my <style> tag, the <span></span>'s visibility is set to hidden. It should only show up when a user click the submit button and has entered an invalid input. My problem is that, whenever I leave blank on the textbox, the span tag isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I haven't provide my entire code that's why some of you are confused.

The reason why it isn't showing up because I have another span on my header. And on my javascript code, I declared spans as an array. As a result, the span on my header was the span[0] index. and the span below the firstname is span[1].

Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't initialize it to hidden first?
You simply initialize it to hidden, and if the user doesn't set it properly, you turn it to visible.

```js
function validate() {
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var fname = document.registration.fname;
  if (fname.value === "") {
    spans[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  }else{
    spans[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name='registration' align='center'>
  <fieldset name='registration' class='fieldset-auto-width'>
    <div>
      <label for='fname'><b>FirstName:</b>
      </label>
      <input type='text' name='fname' placeholder='Enter First Name' value='' required='required' />
      <span id='errfn' class='error' style="visibility:hidden"> required</span>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='validate();' />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```